# emacs: specify 2 or 4 space indentation for C-j electric-newline-and-maybe-indent

Tags: indentation

I'm using emacs 24.  I work on a variety of html files,
sometimes there's blocks of html with two space indentation,
others have four space indentation.

When I press C-j , emacs assumes i want 4 space indentation. How can I quickly tell C-j what kind (2 or 4) indentation I want?

(on my system C-h k gives "electric-newline-and-maybe-indent" for C-j)